# How to know if an mcc-compiled MATLAB function is called in MATLAB or via standalone application?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, mcc

I have a MATLAB function that has been compiled into a standalone application with `mcc`.  When the user works with the function through the standalone application, output arguments are not used and instead I would like to ensure that the user gives an address to an output file as an input argument.

For instance, say my MATLAB function  `myFunc` is defined like this:

```
function out_mat = myFunc(nElem, varargin)
save_file = false;
if nargin == 2
    save_file = true;
    add_to_file = varargin{1};
end
out_mat = rand(nElem);
if save_file
    % Write out_mat to address add_to_file....
end
end
```

When called in MATLAB, the user can define an output address (`add_to_file`) or not. It is up to the user and I do not care! But if the user is using the standalone executable, I want to make sure that the user actually defines `add_to_file`. So basically I want to add a condition like this to my code:

```
if call_in_matlab
    narginchk(1,2);
else
    narginchk(2,2);
end
```

How do I check if `call_in_matlab` is true or false? In other words, how can I tell in a function is called through its compiled standalone application or in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some functions in MATLAB to support Compiler-generated stand-alone programs. See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/standalone-applications.html). In particular, you want [`isdeployed`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/isdeployed.html).